# Are absolute positions in canvas always based on viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, viewport

I understand the difference between absolute coordinates viewport coordinates.

When you specify coordinates, in say fillText(msg, posX, posY) in canvas, are posX and posY viewport coordinates? Because in spite of specifying exact coordinates, like say, (50,50) for (posX,posY), I get the same output, that is, the output string is placed at the same location even in a resized window.

JS fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ud1j4e6m/3/)

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="1000" height="1000">
</canvas>
<script src="without.js">

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS Code
    var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas")
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d')

```
function windowToCanvas(x,y)
{
    var box = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

    return{
        x : (x-box.left) * (canvas.width / box.width),
        y : (y-box.top) * (canvas.height / box.height)
    };
}

context.font = "30px Arial";

var posX = 50;
var posY = 50;

var loc = windowToCanvas(50,50)
var posX = loc.x;
var posY = loc.y;
context.fillText("Hello World!",posX,posY)
```

Comment: positions are relative to the top-left of the canvas itself.

Answer (score 2):

neither. canvas coords are based on the upper left corner of the canvas itself.

all this is unnecessary..

```
function windowToCanvas(x,y)
{
    return {x:x, y:y};

    // You don't need all this
    var box = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return{
        x : (x-box.left) * (canvas.width / box.width),
        y : (y-box.top) * (canvas.height / box.height)
    };
}
```

Comment: To be exact, Canvas coords are based on its context's transformation matrix, which is defaulted to the upper-left corner (1,0,0,1,0,0)